# MacBook Pro 2018 - "You can't open the application "iTunes" because it is being update"

Tags: macos, itunes, software-update

I was installing the updates for iTunes because I wanted to connect my iPhone to my Mac. However, I closed my MacBook prematurely since I didn't realise that they were still updating and now iTunes can't open again. How can I check its current updating progress (if it is at all)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Updates worked for me. I had Safari - can’t open the application Safari because it is being updated.

I went into App Store then updates and clicked update all. That seemed to clear the issue. Safari is back running
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Launch the Mac App Store app and click on the Updates tab. The progress of any currently running update as well as any newly available updates are shown here.

With the Updates tab open, click on the Update icon in the apps toolbar to refresh the check for update.

Comment: I am not given this option as it says "No Updates Available".

Comment: Retry the check for update and restart your computer.

Comment: Sadly I've restarted the computer at least 6 times now. Another additional bit of information that wasn’t in the original question is that I also can't start up the OS in safe mode. I'm seriously regretting buying the 2018 version of the MacBook Pro.

Comment: @Thunder17 Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I get you're frustrated, I would be too, but taking it out on a user who is only trying to help isn't the best way to go. As far as I can tell, their post does *answer* the actual question being asked, namely how to check the current updating progress (if at all). Perhaps it would be useful now to check the site for answers on how you can do a fresh installation of iTunes and if there isn't one, ask a new question about that? Feel free to link back to this question for context.